# How to make access based xmlrpc call for ejabberd from Java client?

Tags: java, xml-rpc, ejabberd, xmlrpclib, xmlrpcclient

I am running ejabberd and ejabberd_xmlrpc module - https://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd_xmlrpc
 In the link I can see python, php and xmlrpc client module with access control. How can we write the same using java client

Here is my code:

```
     /* Code for ejabberd */        
     try {
        XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
        config.setServerURL(new URL("http://ejabberd.sandwitch.in:4560"));
        config.setBasicUserName("nishant@ejabberd.sandwitch.in");
        config.setBasicPassword("freebsd");
        config.setConnectionTimeout(xmlrpcConnTimeout);
        config.setReplyTimeout(xmlrpcReplyTimeOut);
        XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
        client.setConfig(config);

        /* Command string */
        String command = "register";

        /* Parameters as struct */
        Map struct = new HashMap();
        struct.put("user", "nishant");
        struct.put("host", "ejabberd.sandwitch.in");
        struct.put("password", "nishant");

        Map struct1 = new HashMap();
        struct1.put("user", "arbit6");
        struct1.put("host", "ejabberd.sandwitch.in");
        struct1.put("password", "arbit6");          

        Object[] params = new Object[]{struct, struct1};
        HashMap<Object, Object> hashMap = (HashMap<Object, Object>) client.execute(command, params);
        for (Object obj : hashMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(obj));
        }
        for (Object obj : hashMap.values()) {
            System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(obj));
        }
        System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(hashMap.get("text")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

But it is giving an unknown call register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing host in first struct to server. My mistake.